# Add .html to a string Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, addition

I want to check if a string is ending with ".php" extension, if not I want to add .html at the end. I have already tried various "slice" methods without success.

Comment: @ user1317928 please try to explain your question well with code(you tried) if possible from next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex for that

```
var string1 = "www.example.com/index";
var newString = !/\.php$/i.test(string1)? string1+".html": string1;
// newString = "www.example.com/index.html"
```

Comment: Assuming no pathological case of ".php" occurring somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @DaveNewton Nope, he got it ok. Note the `$` marking the end of string.

Comment: @Imp He added that in afterwards, so Dave was correct at the time.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. Huh? Then why is there no `edited ... ago` clause?

Comment: @Imp When you edit withing 5 minutes after posting it doesn't put that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted

Answer (score 1):

Use  `(yourstring + '.html').replace(/\.php\.html$/, '.php')` to do that:

```
var str1 = 'one.php';
var str2 = 'two';
var str3 = '.php.three.php';
var str4 = '.php.hey';

console.log((str1 + '.html').replace(/\.php\.html$/, '.php')); // Prints one.php
console.log((str2 + '.html').replace(/\.php\.html$/, '.php')); // Prints two.html
console.log((str3 + '.html').replace(/\.php\.html$/, '.php')); // Prints .php.three.php
console.log((str4 + '.html').replace(/\.php\.html$/, '.php')); // Prints .php.hey.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps:

```
function appendHTML(string) {
    var html = string;
    if (string.lastIndexOf('.php') === (string.length - 4)) {
        html += '.html';
    }
    return html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to solve your problem.
/.php$/ is a regular expression that checks to see if a string ends with '.php'

For more information read: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp

Example Code:

```
str = "http://abc.com";
str = ( /\.php$/.test( str ) ) ? str : str + '.html'; // this is the line you want.

str === "http://abc.com.html" // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `slice()` works ok for this task.

```
var s = "myfile.php";

if (s.slice(-4) != ".php")
    s = s.slice(0, -4) + ".html";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function isPHP(str)
{
    return str.substring(str.length - 4) == ".php";
}
```

Then you could do

```
str = isPHP(str) ? str : str + ".html";
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `(str.length - 4)`?